# Decode ambiguous Morse code

Tags: java, interview-questions, morse-code

Stumbled upon this interview question:

> Given a morse encoded sentence with no spaces or separation between letters or words and a list of words contained in the message, decode it.

This was my solution (and a test case with the jack and jill sentence):

```
 static String[] alpha = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k",
        "l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v",
        "w","x","y","z"};
static String[] morse = {".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",
        ".--","-..-","-.--","--.."};

private static HashMap<Character, String> letters = new HashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
        letters.put(alpha[i].charAt(0), morse[i]);
    }

    String[] words = {"hill","jack","went","and","jill","the","up"};
    System.out.println(
            decode(".---.--.-.-.-.--.-...---...-...-...--.-.-..-.--.-............-...-..",
                    words)
    );
}

private static String decode(String code, String[] words){
    String[] encodedWords = new String[words.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        encodedWords[i] = encodeWord(words[i]);
    }

    return decodePossibility(code, words, encodedWords, new StringBuilder());
}

private static String decodePossibility(String code, String[] words, String[] encodedWords, StringBuilder current){
    if(code.length() == 0) return current.toString();
    for (int i = 0; i < encodedWords.length; i++) {
        if(code.length() >= encodedWords[i].length()){
            if(code.substring(0, encodedWords[i].length()).equals(encodedWords[i])){
                String result = decodePossibility(code.substring(encodedWords[i].length()), words, encodedWords, current.append(words[i]).append(' '));
                if(result != null){
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private static String encodeWord(String word){
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        stringBuilder.append(letters.get(word.charAt(i)));
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Any tips on how to improve the code? Any alternative solution?
To back track to a correct solution I would prefer throwing an exception, but sadly I'am not allowed to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### White Space

This is hard on my aging eyes:

```
static String[] morse = {".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",
    ".--","-..-","-.--","--.."};
```

This is much easier to read:

```
static String[] morse = {
    ".-",   "-...",  "-.-.",  "-..",   ".",     "..-.",  "--.",   "....",  "..",   ".---",
    "-.-",  ".-..",  "--",    "-.",    "---",   ".--.",  "--.-",  ".-.",   "...",  "-",
    "..-",  "...-",  ".--",   "-..-",  "-.--",  "--.."
};
```

### `alpha[i].charAt(0)`

In the following, you use create 26 strings, and call `.charAt(0)` on each:

```
static String[] alpha = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k",
    "l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v",
    "w","x","y","z"};
static String[] morse = {".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",
    ".--","-..-","-.--","--.."};

private static HashMap<Character, String> letters = new HashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
        letters.put(alpha[i].charAt(0), morse[i]);
    }
```

You could simply use one 26-character string:

```
final static String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

...

for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length(); i++) {
    letters.put(alpha.charAt(i), morse[i]);
}
```

Or you could statically initialize the structure directly:

```
Map<Character, String> letters = Map.of(
    'a', ".-",    'b', "-...",  'c', "-.-.",  'd', "-..",  'e', ".",
    'f', "..-.",  'g', "--.",   'h', "....",  'i', "..",   'j', ".---",
    ... etc ...);
```

### [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

The following code:

```
private static String encodeWord(String word){
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        stringBuilder.append(letters.get(word.charAt(i)));
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

is pretty straight forward.  It could be reduced to 1 line of code with the Stream API, if you are familiar with it:

```
private static String encodeWord(String word){
    return word.chars().mapToObj(i -> letters.get((char) i).collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

### Words & Encoded Words

Right now, you are allocating a parallel array for `encodedWords`, and matching words and encoded words by index.  You could merge these two structures into one object, a `Map<String, String>` where encoded words map to their decoded values.  Passing this object to `decodePossibility` would be more cohesive than two arrays, which could be of different length.

### Efficiency

Continuing with the `Map<String, String>` of decodings...

In `decodePossibility`, you are looping over all `encodedWords` trying each one to see if it is the next possibility in the message.  With 7 words, this isn't too inefficient, but if the list of words was larger, it could be.

Instead, you could find the length of the shortest encoded word, and develop a `Map` of lists of words starting with a prefixes of that length:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> partitioned_decoding;
```

For instance, the encoding of "the" produces the shortest sequence `-.....` of 6 characters, so in `partition_decoding` each key would be the first 6 characters of `encodedWords`, and each value would contain a mapping of `encodedWords` to `words` for only the `encodedWords` starting with that key.

```
"-....."  ->  Map.of("-.....", "the")
".---.-"  ->  Map.of(".---.--.-.-.-", "jack")
".---.."  ->  Map.of(".---...-...-..", "jill")
".--.-."  ->  Map.of(".--.-.-", "went", ".--.-..", "and")
"..-.--"  ->  Map.of("..-.--.", "up")
"......"  ->  Map.of(".......-...-..", "hill")
```

During `decodePossibility`, if `code` was at least 6 characters long, you would fetch the first 6 characters of `code`, look up that entry in `partitioned_decoding`, and if present, loop over that (ideally only 1) entry in that submap.  In the case of `".--.-."`, you'd have to try both `"went"` and `"and"`, but that is only 2 words, which is still much smaller than examining all 7.

Neither `"e"` or `"t"` are valid single letter words, so the worst case would be if `words` contained the word `"a"`, which would cause the key length to reduce to 2 characters, and `words` would be partitioned into 4 different bins: `"--"`, `".-"`, `"-."`, and `".."`, which should still provide a 4 times speed-up, since only one quarter of entries would be checked at each stage.

### Alternative to Recursion

Instead of recursion, you could use a loop, and allocate your own stacks for current position and word iteration for each level.  When a solution is found, the `return` statement would directly return the solution - no need to check for a sub-step returning non-null and returning that value, eventually unwinding the call-stack to the top.  When a dead-end is found, you pop the previous state from your own stacks, and continue looping until a solution is found or no solution is possible.